# ReactJS / Material-UI / Javascript: Can't get rounded borders on TableRow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get rounded borders on TableRow. I've added style "borderRadius: 5" but it doesn't do anything. When I surround TableRow by Box with borderRadius, it does work but then the table spacing is broken.

I've been messing around with this for a while but can't figure out.. What's the best solution for this?

```
<Table>
<TableRow style={{ borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
    <TableCell>
        First table cell
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
        Second table cell
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
        Third table cell
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try add the css in the cell level like below,

```
.MuiTableRow-root td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.MuiTableRow-root td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wing-t8xke?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Do you also know how to remove the borders from the table? I'm getting this https://i.gyazo.com/7f0a0df31f92ef39097669386b565f63.png

Comment: I saw your code and implemented the same but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in sx

```
<TableBody
   sx={{
     "& .MuiTableRow-root th:first-child": {
        borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "10px",
     },
     "& .MuiTableRow-root th:last-child": {
        borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
        borderBottomRightRadius: "10px",
     },
   }}
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

The below way works on adding border radius on MUI Table.

```
<TableContainer
  sx={{
    borderRadius: 2,
    border: 1,
  }}>
  <Table
    size="small"
    sx={{
      borderCollapse: "collapse",
      borderStyle: "hidden",
      "& td": {
        border: 1
      }
    }}>
    {/* table content */}
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Screenshot Example:

[image]